# AngularJS - cannot reference $index inside ng-model using a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I am currently facing an issue whereby I would like to generate a dynamic number of input forms and also name them dynamically (as defined by a JSON) so that I can reference them separately.

For example, if my JSON object had three items in it, I would generate three input boxes with `ng-model="1"`, `ng-model="2"` and `ng-model="3"` respectively. In real life the ID's will come from the JSON itself.

I'm currently using `ng-repeat` to generate the forms in a table;

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
<td>{{ $index }}</td> <!-- this outputs fine  -->
<td>{{ x.Description }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Metric }}</td>
</tr>
```

And using a directive & the `$compile` function to dynamically generate an input form with a unique `ng-model` name.

```
app.directive("outDynamic", function($compile){
return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var template = "<input type='number' ng-model='" + scope.ray[attrs.element1] + "'>";
        var linkFn = $compile(template);
        var content = linkFn(scope);
        element.append(content);
    }
} });
```

However: none of the following works (when nested in the `ng-repeat`)

```
    <!-- None of these work -->
<td out-dynamic element1=$index></td>
<td out-dynamic element1="$index"></td>
<td> <input type='number' ng-model="array[$index]"> </td>
<td> <input type='number' ng-model="array['$index']"> </td>
```

Summary of issue;

> Every time I try and reference the `$index` tracker, I get an
>   undefined error in my directive code.

Comment: where is `scope.ray` in your code?

Comment: It's defined in the controller as $scope.ray = [], I didn't post the whole code to keep the question short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{{}}` to assign `$index` value for attribute. so use

`element1={{$index}}` instead of `element1=$index`

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
     <td out-dynamic element1={{$index}}></td>
     <td out-dynamic element1="{{$index}}"></td>
</tr>
```

I guess your `scope.arr` is perfect.

[PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/KXuxJdPxQHZZG1tXshl6?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That seems to have done the job. It's weird, all the examples I was looking at just referenced $index directly in the quotes.